# Bootstrap carousel not working inside the tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, tabs, carousel

I have a set of tabs each having a carousel inside them with id **#myCarousel, #myCarousel1, #myCarousel2...**.
If I select the 1st tab the slider in it will work, the on selecting 2nd tab slider in it will work too. Then on selecting 1st tab again the slider will not work.

The problemm can be viewed in link
http://www.seomanager.co/project-loyalty-kiosk  .

Can someone please give a solution.

Comment: It actually does work for me, I can go back to first tab and slide again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. You should do it more than on time with more than two tabs.

Comment: You're right, after a lot of going back and forward, switching tabs, it doesn't seem to work, not based on clicks, just random. I'm going to upvote your question, hopefully someone would figure it out soon.

Answer (score 1):

I have just come across the same issue.

- My tabs are all the same height so not sure what you need to do if your tabs vary in height.

Using BS3 scss files, in navs.scss on line 225 the markup sets the non active tabs to 'display:none' so there is no element to populate.

I override BS as below. 'display:block' so the JS can see the element to populate and then set the position to 'position:absolute' so they don't stack.

```
// Tabbable tabs (*default code)
// -------------------------

// Hide tabbable panes to start, show them when `.active`
.tab-content {
    > .tab-pane {
        display: none;
    }
    > .active {
        display: block;
    }
 }

// Tabbable tabs (*amended code)
// -------------------------

// Hide tabbable panes to start, show them when `.active`
.tab-content {
    > .tab-pane {
        // display: none;
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
    }
    > .active {
        display: block;
    }
 }
```

Finally for the layout in your page to work you then need to give .tab-content (I add a class .theme-tab-content) a fixed height that matches the height of your carousel.